# Where are my recent folders in Thunderbird's GTK3 save menu?

Tags: directory, thunderbird, gtk3

My Xubuntu LTS 16.04 desktop recently upgraded Thunderbird from a GTK2 to a GTK3 version.

When saving an e-mail attachment, I no longer see my recently used folders list. However, it still has this for adding e-mail attachments.

How can I see my recently used folders list when saving under GTK3?

Or still better, is there somewhere a PPA to be found with recent thundrbird-gtk2 packages, [like there is on AUR for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/thunderbird-45-gtk2/)?

I am desperate to get some work done!

Comment: [Are GTK+ developers destroying Linux desktop with their plans?](https://fosspost.org/2016/07/08/are-gtk-developers-destroying-linux-desktop-with-their-plans/)

Comment: [The Future of GTK+](https://pipedot.org/story/2014-07-09/the-future-of-gtk)

Comment: OK, I filed a [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1699322). If you are also affected, please, upvote this bug!

Comment: [Rotting In Threes](https://igurublog.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/gnome-et-al-rotting-in-threes/) — Contains the now notorious
William Jon McCann «Boxes-o-crap» and «mascara» quotes!

Comment: And now [GTK3 is also rendering `gvim` buggy](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_missing_gvim_menu_bar_under_GNOME) on Xubuntu LTS!